# How to pass cursor or list of records to java procedure in pl/sql?

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm wondering how to realize the following logic:

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT ( 
   STUDENT_ID       NUMBER (5)      NOT NULL, 
   NAME             VARCHAR2 (255)  NOT NULL, 
   SURENAME         VARCHAR2 (255)  NOT NULL,        
   BIRTH_DATE       DATE            NOT NULL, 
   PRIMARY KEY (STUDENT_ID) 
)
```

Then suppose to find similar Students by calling PL/SQL procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE findStudentByName(p_name IN STUDENT.NAME%TYPE, c_student OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
           IS
  BEGIN
       OPEN c_student FOR
       SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE NAME LIKE p_name || '%';
  END;
  /
```

Then ...

```
DECLARE 
    c_student SYS_REFCURSOR;
    temp_student STUDENT%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  -- records are assign to cursor 'c_student' after calling findStudentByName procedure
  findStudentByName('John',c_student);

    LOOP
       --fetch cursor 'c_student' into STUDENT table type 'temp_student'
       FETCH c_student INTO temp_student;

       -- exit if no more records
       EXIT WHEN c_student%NOTFOUND;

       -- call java procedure the matched name
       -- HOW CAN I PASS ARRAY OF STUDENT%ROWTYPE to java procedure?

    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c_student;
END;
/
```

And my question is how I can pass *ARRAY of records* to **java procedure**?

Comment: check [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/java-tips-jdbc-plsql-stored-procedures-and-custom-prompts) out.

Comment: Check this also : https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/22156191/Passing-a-string-array-from-PL-SQL-to-a-java-function.html

Comment: Where is the Java procedure? Has it been loaded into the database using the [`LOADJAVA` utility](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jjdev/loadjava-tool.html#GUID-B80B4492-55BB-4B75-919C-6E5962380710) or compiled into the database with [`CREATE JAVA`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_5013.htm#SQLRF01211) or is it external to the database?

Comment: @VBokšić So you do advise to use `create or replace type student_rows
as table of STUDENT%ROWTYPE;` instead of cursor, don't you?

Comment: @MT0 Of course!

Comment: @elgolondrino Well if it helped him ... :)

Comment: @VBokšić Need to experiment first!

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] including the code for the Java procedure that you are trying to call (or at the very least its signature) and details of how you loaded it into the database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your stored procedure as a query string either in the Oracle format or the standard JDBC callable statement syntax.

The last code block starting with `DECLARE ..` is not needed, using the stored procedure `findStudentByname` is enough.

Prefer using `REGEXP_LIKE` as

`OPEN c_student FOR SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(NAME,p_name,'i')`.

against case-sensitivity problems for the SQL statement.

By **the Oracle format** :

```
private void findStudent(String name)
 throws SQLException {
    String qry = "begin ? := findStudentByName(?); end;";
    //presuming you already constructed an Oracle connection such as
    // Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    //con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//"+dbname,uname,passwd); 
    CallableStatement stmt = con.prepareCall(qry);

    // the out parameter should be registered as Oracle specific type
    stmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);

    stmt.setFloat(2, name); //pass your filtering parameter

    // execute and retrieve the result set
    stmt.execute();
    ResultSet rs = (ResultSet)stmt.getObject(1);

    // print out the results
    while (rs.next()) {
     System.out.println("STUDENT_ID : "+rs.getLong(1));
     System.out.println("NAME : "+rs.getString(2));
     System.out.println("SURNAME : "+rs.getString(3));
     System.out.println("BIRTH_DATE : "+rs.getDate(4));
   }

   rs.close();
   stmt.close();
}
```

By **the JDBC Syntax**  :

```
private void findStudent(String name)
 throws SQLException {
    String qry = "{ call ? := findStudentByName(?) }";
    CallableStatement stmt = con.prepareCall(qry);

    stmt.registerOutParameter("out_crs", OracleTypes.CURSOR);    
    stmt.setFloat("in_st_name", name); 

    stmt.execute();
    ResultSet rs = (ResultSet)stmt.getObject("out_crs");

    while (rs.next()) {
     System.out.println("STUDENT_ID : "+rs.getLong("student_id"));
     System.out.println("NAME : "+name);
     System.out.println("SURNAME : "+rs.getString("surname"));
     System.out.println("BIRTH_DATE : "+rs.getDate("birth_date"));
   }

   rs.close();
   stmt.close();
}
```